# Netbeans platform. Non-ascii characters in path to app

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform, maven-nbm

I'm create my app by using netbeans platfrom(7.4). I use nbm-maven plugin 3.13. In windows(8 in virtual box), i setup app to folder with cyrilic characters. Next, I launch exe file and have message box("Non-ascii ..."). 
I find bug report https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222850, but status is "RESOLVED FIXED". What should i do for resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by upgrading to Netbeans 8.0.

Comment: Today i tried upgrade to netbeans 8.0 and nbm-maven plugin 3.14. This did not solve the problem.

Comment: I'll see if there's anything else that changed for me which may have helped fix the issue.

Comment: Im solve this problem. In netbeans8_directory/harness/launchers located pre7_app.exe. This launcher is correct working with path wich contain Non-ascii characters. But only for 32-bit system.